# How do I remove the local variable in this partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I think having local variables in the partial is bad but I don't know how to refactor:

partial:

```
<div class="span4">
<% local_revision, latest_svn_revision = get_revision_from current_local_path %>
<ul>
  <li><span class="muted">Local Svn Revision</span>: <b><%= local_revision %></b></li>
  <li><span class="muted">Latest Svn Revision</span>: <b><%= latest_svn_revision %></b></li>
</ul>
```

helper:

```
def get_revision_from(local_path)
  working_info = YAML.load `call svn info \"#{local_path}\"`
  repo_path = working_info['Repository Root']
  repo_info = YAML.load `call svn info \"#{repo_path}\"`

  return working_info['Revision'], repo_info['Revision']
end
```

This method `get_revision_from` returns two results, how can I use these two results in the partial without using local variables?

This partial is used in the header, so I'd like to use it in every page. And if they are used in every page, which controller do I place those two variables?

Comment: You don't give us any idea what `get_revision_from current_local_path` actually does. Why don't you just create instance variables in your controller?

Comment: last detail, where is `current_local_path` defined?

Comment: You can assume it's a constant. It's reading from a config file.

Comment: Why not just have two helpers, one for each item, then you can just say: `<%= get_local_revision current_local_path %>` and `<%= get_latest_svn_revision current_local_path %>`.

Comment: @mbratch I don't want to call the same method twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your helper method into your `ApplicationController`, and refactor it so that it doesn't take a parameter (read in `current_local_path` in the method itself), and so that it instantiates instance variables. Then make it a `before_filter` on the application controller.

```
before_filter :get_revision

def get_revision
  # ...
  @local_revision = working_info['Revision']
  @latest_svn_revision = repo_info['Revision']
end
```

Then in your layout file just use `@local_revision` and `@latest_svn_revision`

Comment: Totally forget "before_filter"!

Comment: Just a side note, I don't know anything about SVN, but you probably don't need to be getting the version number for _every request_? Why not just retrieve this information once in an initializer or config file when the application first loads? :)

Comment: You're right. It doesn't make sense. I'm just trying everything I can think of to practice rails!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get your variables out of your partial, you can pass the values in as parameters. You do it as described in the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables):

```
<h1>New zone</h1>
<%= error_messages_for :zone %>
<%= render partial: "form", locals: {zone: @zone} %>
```

In that example, the value of `@zone` will be available inside of the partial code as `zone`.